# The application crashes and runs at the same time

Tags: c++, sfml

I draw the application menu, having previously written the menu class and the function of this class.

When I launch the application, the menu works for 5-7 seconds, but in Windows the cursor are spinning in the form of a blue circle, which does not bode well. If these 5-7 seconds are idle, the whole screen
turns white, and Windows says that the application is not responding. In this case, if you press where the buttons were broken, these buttons are triggered, the menu closes and the game starts. The problem lies in the description of the menu class, I think.

Code of Menu class:

```
class Menu
{
public:
    Image menuImage1, menuImage2, menuImage3;
    Texture menuTexture1, menuTexture2, menuTexture3;

    int menuNum = 0;
    bool isMenu;

    list <Asteroid*> asteroidsMass;
    list <Asteroid*> ::iterator it;

    Sprite menu1, menu2, menu3;

    Menu()
    {
        menuImage1.createMaskFromColor(Color::Black);
        menuImage2.createMaskFromColor(Color::Black);
        menuImage3.createMaskFromColor(Color::Black);

        menuImage1.loadFromFile("title.jpg");
        menuImage2.loadFromFile("start.jpg");
        menuImage3.loadFromFile("exit.jpg");

        menuTexture1.loadFromImage(menuImage1);
        menuTexture2.loadFromImage(menuImage2);
        menuTexture3.loadFromImage(menuImage3);

        menu1.setTexture(menuTexture1);
        menu2.setTexture(menuTexture2);
        menu3.setTexture(menuTexture3);

        menu1.setPosition(scrX / 2, 200);
        menu2.setPosition((scrX / 2) - 172.5, 300);
        menu3.setPosition((scrX / 2) - 140, 450);

        menu1.setOrigin(300, 75);

        for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
        {
            Asteroid* aster = new Asteroid(rand() % 1200, rand() % 800, 5, 25, 0);
            asteroidsMass.push_back(aster);
        }
        isMenu = true;
    }

    void update(RenderWindow& app)
    {
        while (isMenu)
        {
            menu2.setColor(Color::White);
            menu3.setColor(Color::White);

            app.clear(Color::Black);

            menuNum = 0;

            if (IntRect((scrX / 2) - 172, 300, 360, 100).contains(Mouse::getPosition(app))) { menu2.setColor(Color::Green); menuNum = 2; }
            else if (IntRect((scrX / 2) - 172, 450, 360, 100).contains(Mouse::getPosition(app))) { menu3.setColor(Color::Green);menuNum = 3; }

            if (Mouse::isButtonPressed(Mouse::Left))
            {

                if (menuNum == 2) 
                {
                    for (it = asteroidsMass.begin(); it != asteroidsMass.end(); it++)
                    {
                        Asteroid* asteroid = *it;
                        it = asteroidsMass.erase(it);
                        delete asteroid;
                    }
                    isMenu = false;
                
                }
                if (menuNum == 3) 
                { 
                    for (it = asteroidsMass.begin(); it != asteroidsMass.end(); it++)
                    {
                        Asteroid* asteroid = *it;
                        it = asteroidsMass.erase(it);
                        delete asteroid;
                    }
                    
                    isMenu = false; 
                    app.close(); 
                    
                }

            }

            for (it = asteroidsMass.begin(); it != asteroidsMass.end(); it++)
            {
                app.draw((*it)->EntityShape);
            }

            for (it = asteroidsMass.begin(); it != asteroidsMass.end(); it++)
            {
                (*it)->update();
            }

            app.draw(menu1);
            app.draw(menu2);
            app.draw(menu3);

            app.display();
        }
    }
};
```

All code:
https://pastebin.pl/view/0c1d6c9e

Comment: Having `update()` wait looks weird. You will have to order your library to do "message processing", which is required to Windows GUI applications.

Comment: Why store pointers to asteroids in a `list`? Just write `list<Asteroid> astroidsMass`, then there will also be no more need to call `new` and `delete` manually. Also use range-`for` to iterate over them, for example: `for (auto &asteroid: asteroidsMass) app.draw(asteroid.EntityShape)`.

Comment: The loop inside `menuNum == 2` and `menuNum == 3` is wrong. Remove `it++` in the for loop. Better version: `for(auto aptr : asteroidsMass) delete aptr; asteroidsMass.clear();`

Comment: @MikeCAT What do you mean?

Comment: @CodePenguin32 You have undefined behavior since you delete objects through base class pointers (`Entity*`) - but `Entity`s destructor is not `virtual`.

Comment: undefined behavour  occurs in Menu, in game loop it runs normally withot errors, but i will check that about you say

Comment: I SOLVED MY PROBLEM!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I SOLVED MY PROBLEM!
If you have same problem, just write in "while" loop checking of closing window:

```
while(isMenu)
{
Event event;
    while (app.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == Event::Closed)
                app.close();
        }
//some code
}
```